# FetchedResultsController NSSortDescriptor for one-to-many relationship

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

I have 2 entities: `chat`<->> `chatMessages` (each chat has 0+ messages, each message belongs to one chat).

I'm making `FetchedResultsController` and I'd like to sort chats by date of last message:

```
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ChatModel" inManagedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"chatMessages.messageDate" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

But with this code I get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
```

How can I sort chats in required way? (just like whatsapp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use collective operators.

[Read about it here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)

And the ready answer that you must be expecting would be like creating a sort descriptor like this -

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"chatMessages.@max.messageDate" ascending:NO];
```